# Which Client-server model communication fit's nowadays?

Tags: java, server, client, communication, system-design

I have a server built on Java that interacts with the client written on C# via REST (Client makes requests and somehow behaves out of responses). The client sometimes sends a heartbeat, also via rest, and now I want to implement the client-message system when the server can send info messages to the client while it works. Which level and which technology I should use in this case to have the most efficient and lightweight path to have a messaging system?

I think in way of good old socket connections, as I think that creating a web-server for REST requests/responses on the desktop client is an overhead and probably not all clients would be the accessible cause of NAT of ISP's.

Comment: Do you mean two-way communication?

Comment: Yes, but mostly in cases when the client should receive messages from the server, not as callbacks. Consider all probable problems with connection, like closed ports or restricted access from your ISP provider (clients aren't visible for all users on the internet, usually not visible at all).

Comment: WebSockets should be able to help you. The closed ports and restricted access should not affect anything, as long as the ISP does not block websites :)

Comment: You can use WebSocket for your needs.